# random subsampling of the majority class

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, subsampling

I have an unbalanced data and I want to perform a random subsampling on the majority class where each subsample will be the same size as the minority class ... I think this is already implemented on [Weka](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/SpreadSubsample) and Matlab, is there an equivalent to this on sklearn ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your data looks like something generated from this code:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(100, 3)
y = np.array([int(i % 5 == 0) for i in range(100)])
```

(only a 1/5th of `y` is 1, which is the minority class).

To find the size of the minority class, do:

```
>>> np.sum(y == 1)
20
```

To find the subset that consists of the majority class, do:

```
majority_x, majority_y = x[y == 0, :], y[y == 0]
```

To find a random subset of size 20, do:

```
inds = np.random.choice(range(majority_x.shape[0]), 20)
```

followed by

```
majority_x[inds, :]
```

and

```
majority_y[inds]
```

Comment: thanks but it split it to training,testing sets ... I want to randomly subsample the training set only, is it still possible to use it ?I am not sure how the function has been implemented in Weka in detail but I am looking for the same

Comment: Got it, misunderstood your question. Will write a different answer.

Comment: Sorry forgot to ask .. How can I replace the new sample majority_x and majority_y with the old one in x and y in order to use it with the other class as an input for a classifier ?

Comment: @user2739381 I'll be very happy to have a look, but could you please open it as a separate question? It's very difficult to hold a dialog in the comments section.

Comment: Many thanks, I did submit it in another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106112/subsampling-classifying-using-scikit-learn