# Subsampling + classifying using scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using Scikit-learn for a binary classification task.. and I have:
Class 0: with 200 observations 
Class 1: with 50 observations

And because I have an unbalanced data.. I want to take a random subsample of the majority class where the number of observations will be the same as the minority class and want to use the new obtained dataset as an input to the classifier .. the process of subsampling and classifying can be repeated many times .. I've the following code for the subsampling with mainly the help of [Ami Tavory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510736/ami-tavory)

```
docs_train=load_files(rootdir,categories=categories, encoding='latin-1')

X_train = docs_train.data
y_train = docs_train.target

majority_x,majority_y=x[y==0,:],y[y==0]  # assuming that class 0 is the majority class
minority_x,minority_y=x[y==1,:],y[y==1]

inds=np.random.choice(range(majority_x.shape[0]),50)
majority_x=majority_x[inds,:]
majority_y=majority_y[inds]
```

It works like a charm, however, at the end of processing the majority_x and majority_y I want to be able to replace the old set that represent class0 in X_train, y_train with the new smaller set in order to pass it as follow to the classifier or the pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer',  CountVectorizer( tokenizer=tokens, binary=True)),
    ('classifier',SVC(C=1,kernel='linear')) ])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

What I have done In order to solve this:
since the resulted arrays where numpy arrays, and because I am new to the whole area and I am really trying very hard to learn .. I've tried to combine the two resulted arrays together majority_x+minority_x in order to form the training data that I want .. I couldn't it gave some errors which I am trying to solve until now ... but even if I could .. how can I keep their index so the majority_y and minority_y will be true as well !

Comment: Just to make sure this isn't an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): is it possible that you're actually looking for something like [stratified cross validation in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html)? Maybe you could briefly explain why (if at all) this is a different problem then building a CV pipeline for imbalanced data in general?

Comment: From the example on the page you have given me it looks like the stratified function will always return a training and testing set which is different to my case ... I am working until now only on the training set ... I want to provide the test set later because it has been splitted based on a different criteria and not based on random split

Comment: If I understand your question (how to merge the newly subsampled sets together) you might want to look into `numpy.concatenate((majority_x,minority_x))`. And as an additional comment, you might want to add `replace=False` to your random.choice in order to prevent sampling the same sample multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After processing majority_x and minority_y you can merge your training sets with

```
X_train = np.concatenate((majority_x,minority_x))
y_train = np.concatenate((majority_y,minority_y))
```

Now X_train and y_train will first contain the chosen samples with y=0 and then the samples with y=1.

An idea for your **related question**:
Make your choice of the majority samples by creating a random permutation vector of the length of the number of your majority samples.
Then choose the first 50 indices of that vector, then the next 50 and so on. 
When you are through with that vector, each sample will have been chosen exactly once. 
If you want more iterations or the remaining permutation vector is too short, you can resort back to random choice.

As I mentioned in my comment, you might also want to add the parameter "replace=False" in your np.random.choice, 
*if* you want to prevent having the same sample multiple times in one iteration.

Comment: thanks, .. I've done what you have suggested and all was wring really great in a small program .. until I move it to my original program .. it looks like the original x_train is not a list of lists as I we thought ! it's just a list with an appended 'u' at the beginning of each item !.. I am loading my original data from text files is this is the reason ! and how can I go around that

Comment: @user2739381 What is the output for `print(type(x_train))`? If it really is just a list I don't think you could do `majority_x = x_train[y==0,:]` (by the way, in your question you have `majority_x = x[y==0,:]` is that x the same as x_train?)
You can also try to cast the list into a numpy array with `np.array(x_train)` though I am not sure what will happen.

Comment: Yes it's a list and I'vs cast it into numpy array and I've changed the majority code to majority_x=x[y==0] .. It worked .. What wrong can happen do you think

Comment: So does concatenate work now? If it is a list, you should have been able to merge them with `majority_x + minority_x`.